# Adding ellipsis to table <th> the containing arrow causing do not appear

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In a table i have a very long header text in several columns that also contains an arrow icon that is added with:

```
.ascending a:after,
.ascending .glyphicon:before {
    content: "\e253";
}
```

[this is an example](https://codepen.io/eranmeir1z/pen/EvKrbO)

what i want to achieve is that in the column header text that is shown with `ellipsis`, after the 3 comma's the arrow will appear correctly

**Header | Long text Long te... ^ | Header**

- I don't wont to use `fixed` as it responsive table
- for seeing the `arrow` in the code pen > delete the `ellipsis` class from the

  `<th class="**ellipsis** ascending glyphicon">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.table{width:700px;}
a:link{color: #337ab7;}

.ascending a:after,
.ascending .glyphicon:before {
 content: "\e253";
  position:absolute;
  right:1px;
}

.ellipsis{
    max-width:100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>header</th>
        <th class="ellipsis ascending glyphicon">
          <a href="#">long header long header long header long header long header long header long header long header long header long header 
          </a>
        </th>
        <th>header</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Thanks! but when i add your css > this what happens, i dont know why.. maybe there are more `position` that are being set via the css. http://imgur.com/a/zZmZa maybe you'll know why? I marked the arrow with red square

Comment: i also added position relative to every `th`